# snowflake Connection error in python " snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 251005: User is empty"

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm a newbie to snowflake and trying to connect to the db using python but when executing the code i get this error "snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 251005: User is empty"

```
import snowflake.connector

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(

       username = 'xxx',

       password = 'xxxx',

       account = 'xxxx'

       )

cs = ctx.cursor()

try:

  cs.execute(''' some query''')

  one_row = cs.fetchone()

  print(one_row[0])

finally:

  cs.close()

ctx.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use "user" parameter instead of "username". Here's sample:

```
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='XXXX',
    password='XXXX',
    account='XXXX'
)
```

Please check: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#setting-session-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Also, it's case sensitive (I had the same error message with USER)